# Клиент-Сервер. Параллельная обработка запросов (один поток) посредством функции select.

Tags: c, сокет

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане! =)
Не могу написать простую клиент-серверскую программку, в которой сервер просто выводит то, что присылает ему клиент. Т.е. запускаю клиентов несколько, пересылаю сколько мне захочется сообщений из каждого, вижу, что сервер их выводит правильно, выхожу. Запросы клиентов обслуживаются сервером параллельно. Делал подобное как с помощью создания дополнительных процессов, так и с помощью создания дополнительных потоков. А как сделать это с помощью функции select ()?

```
int main ()
{
    int mainSock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
    struct sockaddr_in host;
    host.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
    host.sin_family = AF_INET;
    host.sin_port = htons (2000);
    bind (mainSock, (struct sockaddr*)&host, sizeof host);
    listen (mainSock, 5);

    fd_set SET;
    fd_set READ;

    FD_ZERO (&SET);
    FD_SET (mainSock, &SET);
    int N = getdtablesize ();
    while (true)
    {
        memcpy (&READ, &SET, sizeof SET);
        select (N, &READ, NULL, NULL, (struct timeval*)0);
        if (FD_ISSET(mainSock, &READ))
        {
            int newSock = accept (mainSock, NULL, NULL);
            FD_SET (newSock, &SET);
        }
        //.........
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Только начал разбираться с этой функцией. Поэтому за какое-то непонимание сильно не ругайте. Просто я вот думаю: Допустим, ко мне присоединился новый клиент, я добавляю дескриптор в SET. Дальше вот не знаю, как проверять каждый дескриптор, на случай, если мне какой-то клиент что-то прислал и еще одновременно смотреть не присоединились ли новые клиенты. Повторюсь, только начал разбираться с функцией select и вообще многого, наверное, не понимаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В man написано, что N (в Вашем случае) это **максимальный номер + 1** для дескрипторов в передаваемых в select множеств дескрипторов. По поводу getdtablesize есть замечание

```
The  libc4 and libc5 versions return
OPEN_MAX (set to 256 since Linux 0.98.4).
```

IMHO в Ваших тестах работать наверняка будет, но я обычно отслеживаю максимум (однажды достигнутый, т.е. при close дескриптора max не пересчитаваю).

Неплохо бы проверять возвращаемый select результат и использовать его при обработке ставших активными дескрипторов. В любом случае его надо проверить на -1 и в этом случае посмотреть errno. errno == EINTR говорит об каком-то обработанном сигнале. Обычно возвращаемся  на select (у Вас можно continue;).

Полученные из accept дескрипторы запоминайте в списке. При возврате из select (и если активность не на mainSock) в цикле просматривайте список и проверяете (FD_ISSET) стал ли этот дескриптор активным. Если да, то можно читать поступившие данные.

Другой вариант (без списка) это цикл

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
    if (FD_ISSET(i,&READ) ...
```

Если написать

```
Select: memcpy(...); 
n = select(N,...);
```

то после обработки очередного дескриптора можно

```
if (--n == 0) break; // это где-то во внутреннем цикле
```

вернуться на select.

Насколько я понял, Вы хотите обрабатывать запросы без потоков/процессов. Тогда советую, используя fcntl сделать этот сокет неблокируемым

```
int x=fcntl(s,F_GETFL,0);
fcntl(s,F_SETFL,x | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Логика обработки несколько усложнится (из за дополнительных проверок результата send/recv), но не подвисните на чтении.

Обычно обработка запроса (прочитанного блока) без потоков/процессов должна быть короткой и Вы делаете ее прямо после FD_ISSET.

Ну, пожалуй я уже иссяк. Задавайте конкретные вопросы, попробую ответить.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, что откликнулись и не поленились потратить на меня свое время :)